# Bootstrap button doesn't route when clicked

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

**the following button should route to lead index view but it does not work**

```
<label class="btn btn-white btn-md waves-effect">
        <a href="{{ route('lead.index') }}" class="btn btn-default">LEAD</a></label>
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: why minus, i really do not understand the issue or even debug it. i also tried this  <button href="{{ route('normindex') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="btn btn-white btn-md waves-effect">
   <a href="lead.index" class="btn btn-default">LEAD</a>
</label>
```

Comment: it does not work too, plus i need the Route function. @Ank